# Translating virtual address to physical address in kernel space

Tags: linux, block, linux-device-driver, device-driver, virtual-address-space

How to convert virtual address to physical address in kernel space?
Using :

```
 #include <asm/io.h>

 phys_addr = virt_to_phys(virt_addr);
 virt_addr = phys_to_virt(phys_addr);
 bus_addr = virt_to_bus(virt_addr);
 virt_addr = bus_to_virt(bus_addr);
```

Comment: So, what is a question? You ask "how to .." and immediately provide code, which probably do that. If this code doesn't work for you, note that in the question post.

Comment: No no i do not need the code just a procedure, explanation how i am going to implement it or any algorithm

Comment: Functions you list in the code are already defined in "asm/io.h", you may use them. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes that i know, but i am getting how to use it. Because in that virt_addr how to use it.

Comment: Then your real question is _How to use a virtual address in kernel space?_? - If your English is not sufficient to express your question, you should ask someone to put it for you.